# Is it possible to detect a session timeout?

Tags: asp.net, session

As part of our security audit, we have to ensure that when a user logs out we clear the session ID (not just the session) and use a new session ID.

However, currently if a user's session simply times out, the session ID is re-used for the next session.

Is there any way to detect if a session has timed out, and create a new session ID at that time?

Comment: The way we handle it is by catching the exception and handling the cases where the message indicates a timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this method: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21156/ASP-NET-HttpModule-for-handling-session-end-with-S

But it does not work in our case since we are using a server farm.

Instead I ended up using NWebsec.SessionSecurity (https://www.nuget.org/packages/NWebsec.SessionSecurity/) and it handled all of that out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article on session ID resuse https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/899918.

Adding this code to either the logout or session_end methods

```
Session.Abandon(); 
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
```

And in Web.config

```
<sessionState regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"></sessionState>
```

I haven't had a need for this, however it seems like this is at the very least a good starting point for you.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really answer my question.